# Label in a QToolbar

Tags: qt, label, qtoolbar

How would you suggest to add a label on a QToolbar ? Since it only accepts action or somethings like that.

Thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `QToolBar` also accepts widgets like a `QLabel` through the method [`QToolBar::addWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbar.html#addWidget).

Answer (score 17):

As abresas wrote, a toolbar can be populated with a [QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtoolbar.html#addAction-3).
The QString passed along with the QAction is used in several ways (e.g as tooltip), but with 4.8 the default is to show a toolbar button with the icon only.
To show the text with the icon, set the toolbar to a [Qt::ToolButtonStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ToolButtonStyle-enum), e.g.

```
ui->toolBar->setToolButtonStyle( Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon );
```

Comment: I had to do  `ui->mainToolBar->setToolButtonStyle( Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon  );` in Qt 5.4

Comment: strangely enough the text shows up tripped in the bottom for long characters like 'g'. Any idea why that  might be?

Answer (score -2):

You just pass the string to addAction method.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html

```
QAction *   addAction ( const QString & text )
```

Comment: If you do it like this then it is also a button